# Extract values from child XML tag that has the same parent tag using python

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to extract roll numbers from an XML file using python. I used to be able to retrieve the appropriate element using getElementsByTagName('RollNumber').

A parent tag with the very same child tag name has now been added to the XML generation. When I run the script I an error stating **Element instance has no attribute 'data'**.

```
<RollNumbers>
    <RollNumber>
        <RollNumber>1234567891011120000</RollNumber>
    </RollNumber>
</RollNumbers>
```

I've attached my script below:

```
import arcpy,sys,os,xml.dom.minidom

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fname = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fxml = open(fname, 'r')

if fxml != None:
    XMLData = fxml.read()
    fxml.close()

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(XMLData)
node = dom.documentElement

rollTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('RollNumber')

RollNums = []
for RollNumber in rollTag:
    nodes = RollNumber.childNodes
    for node in nodes:
        arn = node.data[:15]
        arcpy.AddMessage(arn)
        RollNums.append(arn)

rolllen = len(RollNums)
arcpy.AddMessage(rolllen)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are assuming all child nodes of a `RollNumber` element are Text nodes.  However, the parent `RollNumber` element in your XML document has another element as one of its children and you cannot return the `data` for an element.

One way to handle the problem is to replace the line

```
rollTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('RollNumber')
```

with

```
rollTag = [ element for element in dom.getElementsByTagName('RollNumber')
                     if not element.getElementsByTagName('RollNumber') ]
```

`dom.getElementsByTagName('RollNumber')` returns all elements with the tag name `RollNumber`.  For each such element we find the child elements that also have the name `RollNumber`.  If any are found then `element` is a parent node and is excluded from the list returned to `rollTag`.  `rollTag` thus ends up containing only the child `RollNumber` nodes.

Alternatively, you could replace the lines

```
        arn = node.data[:15]
        arcpy.AddMessage(arn)
        RollNums.append(arn)
```

with

```
        if isinstance(node, xml.dom.minidom.Text) and node.data.strip():
            arn = node.data[:15]
            arcpy.AddMessage(arn)
            RollNums.append(arn)
```

This checks that the child node of the `RollNumber` element is a Text node and also that it contains something other than whitespace.  In your sample XML document, your parent `RollNumber` element has two child nodes that are both Text nodes containing only whitespace, but you want to ignore them.

Both approaches should handle any number of nested `RollNumber` elements, provided the data you want to read is only ever in the innermost `RollNumber` element.  They will behave differently if parent nodes also contain text, for example:

```
<RollNumbers>
    <RollNumber>
        <RollNumber>1234567891011120000</RollNumber>
        ABCDEFG
    </RollNumber>
</RollNumbers>
```

The first approach would return only `123456789101112` but the second approach would also pick up the text `ABCDEFG`.

Comment: Hey Luke, I used your first approach and it worked perfectly!  Thank you very much for your help.  Cheers!